# Check if a key already exists in a dict in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user to input an item and a quantity and if the item is already stocked in the "database", which is  my txt file, it add the quantity to the already existing item.

```
 def item_list():
   my_dict = dict()
   add_item = input("Enter item name: ")
   add_quantity = input("Enter quantity of {0} : ".format(add_item))
   int_quantity = int(add_quantity)
   my_dict[add_item] = int_quantity

   with open("groceries.txt", "a") as text_file:
        if add_item in my_dict.keys():
            print("item {0} already exists".format(add_item))
            addqte = my_dict[add_item]+ int_quantity
            my_dict[add_item] = addqte
            text_file.write(str(my_dict))
        else :
            text_file.write(str(my_dict))
            print(" {0} {1} added  .".format(add_quantity, add_item))
        text_file.close()


show_list()
```

Actual result: says its already in the dict and just double the quantity  (even if the dict was empty before the input) and create a new key

Expected result: Should write a new item and its quantity or if the item is already in the dict, add the quantity input but does not create another instance of that same item.

I feel like it takes my newly added item and says its already in the dict so it always go in the if section. Any idea on what to do next?

Comment: It's already in the dict because you just added it two lines before: `my_dict[add_item] = int_quantity`. `my_dict` doesn't contain anything from the file, it just contains the one item you just added.

Comment: To simply check if a key is in a dictionary do "if key in d: pass"

Comment: @badatprogramming123, what is the format of your "database"?

Comment: if you want to check key in file then you have to read all file to `dict()`, check key in this dict and if you add new key then write dict back to file (replace previous content).

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the data from the file into `my_dict` first. Then you update the dict with the new quantity, and finally you overwrite the entire file from the dict.

```
def item_list():
    with open("groceries.txt", "r") as text_file:
        my_dict = {item: int(quantity) for item, quantity in map(lambda line: line.split(), text_file)}
    add_item = input("Enter item name: ")
    add_quantity = input("Enter quantity of {0} : ".format(add_item))
    int_quantity = int(add_quantity)
    if add_item in my_dict:
        print("item {0} already exists".format(add_item))
        my_dict[add_item]+= int_quantity
    else:
        my_dict[add_item] = int_quantity
        print(" {0} {1} added  .".format(add_quantity, add_item))

    with open("groceries.txt", "w") as text_file:
        for item, quantity in my_dict.items():
            text_file.write(f"{item} {quantity}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers ! Im new at programming and this help a lot. The solution you gave me totally make sense, but im not sure how to interprete the my_dict line {item: quantity for item, quantity in map(lambda line: line.split(), text_file)}   Also I believe it returns an error : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Can you show what the file looks like? I assumed it was item and quantity separated by a space. That error means there's more than 2 words on a line.

Comment: That line in the code is a dictionary comprehension. It's like a list comprehension, but it creates a dictionary instead. It reads each line, splits it into two words, and uses the first word as the item name, the second word as the quantity, then turns that into an entry in the dictionary.

Comment: The file was full of my random tests thats why it didnt work ! Your code is fine, oops. Otherwise the file is just an empty text file. Also Thanks for the definition, that was way better than w3schools.